# How to use shell variables within a python script

Tags: python, shell

I'd like to get shell variable content **to be used within a python script**, specifically to get path out of it to be used later for a function call to a python script located at another directory, using `sys.path.insert`

Let's assume my shell variable is called `SHELL_VAR1`, and I want to concatenate to it `/scripts` folder name, so I get flow like that - using in this example `os.environ.get` just to illustrate my need in case it was environment variable and not a shell variable - and the question is what should be used instead:

```
python -c 'import os; import sys;var1=os.environ.get('SHELL_VAR1'); sys.path.insert(1, 'var1' ''/scripts'');'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call an external command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-an-external-command)

Comment: No, as far as I see, since I want to embed the result within the python script -Jakob's answer below helped me, thanks

Comment: and the question there is more generalized than mine, so I get 'lost' with the answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shell variable and environment variable are the same thing, in my understanding.

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for OS-agnostic filepath operations (like joining filepaths).

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

# This will raise a KeyError if the key is not in os.environ.
var1 = os.environ["SHELL_VAR1"]
path = Path(var1) / "scripts"
sys.path.insert(1, str(path))
```